# Why does Eclipse apply double-indent to some statements?

Tags: eclipse, indentation, code-formatting

For some statements, it seems that the Eclipse formatter applies double indentation. If you open the formatter dialog in the preferences, you have:

```
class Point {
public:
    Point(double x, double y) :
            x(x), y(y) {
    }
    /* etc. */
```

there seems to be no way to tell the formatter to do:

```
class Point {
public:
    Point(double x, double y) :
        x(x), y(y) {
    }
    /* etc. */
```

instead. Why is that? And what can I do about it?

<sub>(I'm using Eclipse Kepler but this is not a new phenonmenon.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because non-finished lines have 2 indentations (and the plugin devs consider the constructor args as the part of the previous line).

For instence, if you write something like this:

```
class Point extends GeometricStuff {
  ...
}
```

And write extends into a new line, I believe it will be indented twice:

```
class Point
        extends GeometricStuff { // Note the double indentation here.
  ...
}
```

The reason is that when you write code sequentially, you can easily recognize where does a given line ends (one could get messed up easily by all the `if-while-for` indentations otherwise):

```
System.out.println("A");
System.out.println("B name: "+ 
        b.name + ", " +
        b.age + " year(s) old");
System.out.println("C");
```

Comment: But I don't *want* unfinished lines to have double indentation... what's wrong with single? :-(  Anyway, how come Eclipse doesn't let me control this?

Comment: It's not Eclipse, it's the CDT plug-in that does not support this. The Java formatter is quite sophisticated and can deal with those situations. It's a personal preference but I find it useful (esp. if you look on a team mate's code who likes to avoid optional parentheses). If there's really no support for this, the CDT plug-in is an open source one, contributions are always more than welcomed :-)

Comment: I know I'm being lazy, but if you're involved with CDT development work, could I trouble you to refer me to where the formatter sources are?

Comment: I don't know the internals of the CDT plugin, but you can start here: https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/developers.php